# java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing a simple music player. So there is a SeekBar that is updated by the Thread. But when I select a song for the second time, then it crashes (  java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started ).

This is my code:

```
updateSeekBar = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = 0;
        while(mp != null && currentPosition<totalDuration){
            try{
                sleep(500);
                currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Thread ERROR" );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

...

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Thread State: " + updateSeekBar.getState().toString());
                    Uri u = Uri.parse(songList.get(position).getPath().toString());
                    if(mp!=null){ mp.stop(); mp.reset(); mp.release(); }
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                    mp.start();
                    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                    updateSeekBar.start();
                    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
                            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                        }
                    });
```

How could I avoid the crash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I avoid the crash ?

don't use a `Thread` for this kind of task. Every view has a Handler. You can use it to post a runnable with delay that updates your seekbar. E.g.

```
public class MyUpdater implements Runnable {

   MediaPlayer mp;
   SeekBar sb;

   public MyUpdater(MediaPlayer mp, SeekBar sb) {
        this.mp = mp;
        this.sb = sb;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
     int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
     int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
     if (currentPosition<totalDuration) {
        sb.removeCallbacks(this);
        return;
     }   
     sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
     sb.postDelayed(this, 500);
  }  
}
```

Keep `MyUpdater` as member,

```
 final MyUpdater mUpdater;
```

and `onItemClick` just do

```
 sb.removeCallbacks(mUpdater);
 mUpdater = new MyUpdater(mp, sb);
 sb.post(mUpdater);
```

Comment: logcat: Error:(118, 23) error: cannot find symbol method removeAllCallbacks(MyUpdater)

Comment: Error:(9, 8) error: MyUpdater is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in Runnable

Comment: did you copy paste it ?

Comment: I have only edited this: run(MediaPlayer mp, SeekBar sb)

Comment: Because it says: Error:(12, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable mp Error:(15, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable sb

Answer (score 2):

You have to check state of that thread before starting it.

```
if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)  {
          thread.start();  
}
```